# Does revert() send received ether back to sender?

Tags: solidity

When `revert()` undoes all state changes, does that include sending any received ether back to the sender?

For example, would both `sendBackOne()` and `sendBackTwo()` send ether back to the sender?

```
function sendBackOne() public payable {
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
}

function sendBackTwo() public payable {
    revert();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `revert()` will undo all state changes and refund any left over gas.

In your specific example, both functions will send the ether back to the sender.